# How to hide the refresh button on the report viewer control (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have a strange scenario wherein I am having to delete the data from the table once a report is generated. The data gets uploaded to the table when the user clicks on a "Generate Report" button on the web page.

My problem is that once the report is generated and shown on the report viewer control I don't want the user to click on the "Refresh" button on the ReportViewer pane. Is there a way I can hide it?

Answer (score 3):

Forget it, very stupid of me. Its under "Toolbar" properties on the ReportViewer control. ShowRefreshButton.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="viewerName" runat="server" ShowRefreshButton="false" AsyncRendering="false" SizeToReportContent="True" >
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have control over the web page? If so, add a bit of javascript that hides the button.

Using jQuery:

```
<html>

<head>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#btnid').hide(); }
)

</script>
</head>

<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```